# recorrer un array y comparar los elementos

Tags: array, bucle-for, else

Esto es lo que llevo del codigo, pero tengo problemas para que me lea el jackpoint y el fail.

**function ideas(array)** {
// La funcion llamada 'ideas' recibe un array 'array' de strings como parametro
// entre estas ideas hay algunas buenas y otras no, si no encontramos una 'buena' retornamos 'Fail!'
// si encontramos por lo menos una 'buena' retornamos 'Activa!'
// y si encontramos al menos 3 'buena' retornamos 'Jackpot!'
// Por ej:
// ideas(['hola', 'palabra']) debe devolver 'Fail!'
// ideas(['hola', 'buena', 'hi']) debe devolver 'Activa!'
// Tu código aca:

```
var buenaIdea = array.indexOf("buena")
      if (buenaIdea > 3){
      return "Jackpot!"; 
      } else if(buenaIdea < 3) {
       return "Activa!"
      } else if (buenaIdea = 0){
        return "Fail!"
      }
   }
```

Comment: Para comparar igualdad debes usar `==` o `===`. Por otro lado, `indexOf` devuelve `-1` si no se encuentra el elemento en el Array, no veo que estés capturando ese posible caso.

Comment: si lo pensé y cambie el index0f  por hasOwnProperty pero aun se rompe el código

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu código tiene problemas porque estás usando mal la información obtenida. Además, no te piden la posición de la cadena, sino cuantas veces aparece la misma en el Array.

El método [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) de Array devuelve el índice del elemento en el Array. Pero si el Array no contiene dicho elemento, devuelve `-1`.

Por otro lado, la comparación de elementos en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) se realiza con los siguientes operadores:

- `>`: devuelve verdadero si el operando de la izquierda es mayor que el de la derecha, de lo contrario devuelve falso
- `<`: devuelve verdadero si el operando de la izquierda es menor que el de la derecha, de lo contrario devuelve falso.
- `===`: devuelve verdadero si los operandos son iguales y del mismo tipo.

Tu estás usando:

```js
} else if (buenaIdea = 0){
```

lo cual es incorrecto, ya que estás **asignando** el valor 0 a la variable `buenaIdea`. El resultado de esta asignación es luego evaluado en el contexto booleano, y dado que el valor de la variable es cero, se considera `false`.

```js
let variable;
if(variable = 0) {
  console.log('Variable establecida a cero');
}

if(variable = 1) {
  console.log('Variable establecida a uno');
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para resolver el problema, debes tener una forma de contar la cantidad de veces que aparece la cadena "buena" en el Array.

Por ejemplo, usando un simple bucle `for` y un contador:

```js
let cont = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  if (array[i] === "buena") {
    cont++;
  }
}

if (cont === 0) {
  return "Fail!";
}

if (cont < 3) {
  return "Active!";
}

if (cont >= 3) {
  return "Jackpot!";
}
```

Otra forma podría ser usando una función reductora, que devolverá un valor numérico. Este valor se calcula comparando el valor del elemento actual y dependiendo de si es la cadena "buena" se suma al acumulado una unidad, de lo contrario se suma 0.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const array = ["buena", "mala", "no", "buena"];


const cont = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if(cur === "buena") {
    return acc + 1;
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}, 0);

console.log(cont); // 2
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Otra forma de lograr el objetivo sería usando el método [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), para filtrar del array inicial sólo aquellos elementos que se corresponden con la cadena "buena", luego basta ver el tamaño del array resultante y devolver el mensaje apropiado. Por ejemplo:

```js
const array = ["buena", "mala", "no", "buena"];

const filtrado = array.filter(element => element === "buena");

console.log(filtrado.length); // 2
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Por lo tanto, una función que realice la tarea que se pide podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
function ideas(array) {
  const cont = array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if(cur === "buena") {
      return acc + 1;
    } else {
      return acc;
    }
  }, 0);
  
  return cont === 0 ? "Fail!" : cont < 3 ? "Active!" : "Jackpot!";
}

console.log(ideas([])); // Fail!
console.log(ideas(['hola', 'palabra'])); // Fail!
console.log(ideas(['hola', 'buena', 'hi'])); // Active!
console.log(ideas(['buena', 'hola', 'buena', 'buena', 'tres'])); // Jackpot!
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

¡Buenas!, he estado revisando tu código y lo que pasa es que hay un error, indexOf devuelve el lugar del valor más cercano dentro de un array.

Ejemplo:

```
// Ubicaciones: 0 ,  1 ,  2 ,  3
let miArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

let ubicacionDeA = miArray.indexOf("a") // 0
let ubicacionDeB = miArray.indexOf("b") // 1
let ubicacionDeC = miArray.indexOf("c") // 2
let ubicacionDeD = miArray.indexOf("d") // 3
```

Un método sencillo de hacer lo que buscas es este:

```
let array = ["buena", "buenaz", "manzana"]; // Array de ejemplo
let mensaje = "";
var buenaIdea = array.filter(e => e === "buena"); // Filtra las entradas a solo "buena".
                                                  // Por lo que tendríamos algo como esto
                                                  // buenaIdea = ["buena"]

if(buenaIdea.length >= 3) { // Si buenaIdea contiene 3 o más "buena"
    mensaje = "Jackpot!";
} else if(buenaIdea.length >= 1) { // Si buenaIdea contiene menos de 3 pero 1 o más "buena"
    mensaje = "Activa!";
} else { // Si buenaIdea no contiene ningún "buena"
    mensaje = "Fail!";
}
```

¡Salúdos!